# Shortest Service Time First - Priority Queueing in Omnet++

Tags: c++, omnet++

Let me start by saying this is my first time using the omnet++ environment. I'm trying to implement a priority queue, where the messages with the shortest service time are served first. In my case, the service time is set as uniform(0, "another_value" s).
This is my code so far:

```
> 
> 
> #include <omnetpp.h>
> 
> 
> using namespace omnetpp;
> 
> 
> class Queue : public cSimpleModule
> {
> protected:
> cMessage *msgInServer;
> cMessage *endOfServiceMsg;
> 
> cQueue queue;
> 
> simsignal_t qlenSignal;
> simsignal_t busySignal;
> simsignal_t queueingTimeSignal;
> simsignal_t responseTimeSignal;
> 
> double avgServiceTime;
> 
> bool serverBusy;
> 
> 
> public:
> Queue();
> virtual ~Queue();
> 
> protected:
> virtual void initialize() override;
> virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg) override;
> void startPacketService(cMessage *msg);
> void putPacketInQueue(cMessage *msg);
> 
> public:
> static int MyCompareFunc(cObject* a, cObject* b);
> 
> };
> 
> Define_Module(Queue);
> 
> int Queue::MyCompareFunc(cObject *a, cObject *b) {
> 
> cMessage *messageA = check_and_cast<cMessage *>(a);
> cMessage *messageB = check_and_cast<cMessage *>(b);
> 
> serviceTime = exponential(avgServiceTime);
> maybe processing time is simTime()+serviceTime?
> double avgServiceTimeA = messageA->par("avgServiceTime").doubleValue();
> double avgServiceTimeB = messageB->par("avgServiceTime").doubleValue();
> double processingTimeA = exp(avgServiceTimeA);
> double processingTimeB = exp(avgServiceTimeB);
> 
> these work but it's basically FIFO
>     //double processingTimeA = (check_and_cast<cMessage*>(a))->getArrivalTime().dbl();
>     //double processingTimeB = (check_and_cast<cMessage*>(b))->getArrivalTime().dbl();
> 
> if (processingTimeA < processingTimeB)
> return -1;
> else if (processingTimeA > processingTimeB)
> return 1;
> else
> return 0;
> }
> 
> Queue::Queue()
> {
> msgInServer = endOfServiceMsg = nullptr;
> }
> 
> Queue::~Queue()
> {
> delete msgInServer;
> cancelAndDelete(endOfServiceMsg);
> }
> 
> void Queue::initialize()
> {
> 
> endOfServiceMsg = new cMessage("end-service");
> queue.setName("queue");
>     //cQueue queue("queue", MyCompareFunc); //moved this in putPacketInQueue, here it seemed to do nothing
> serverBusy = false;
> 
>     //signal registering
> qlenSignal = registerSignal("qlen");
> busySignal = registerSignal("busy");
> queueingTimeSignal = registerSignal("queueingTime");
> responseTimeSignal = registerSignal("responseTime");
> 
>     //initial messages
> emit(qlenSignal, queue.getLength());
> emit(busySignal, serverBusy);
> 
>     //get avgServiceTime parameter
> avgServiceTime = par("avgServiceTime").doubleValue();
> }
> 
> void Queue::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
> {
> if (msg->isSelfMessage()) { //Packet in server has been processed
> 
>         //log service completion
> EV << "Completed service of " << msgInServer->getName() << endl;
> 
>         //Send processed packet to sink
> send(msgInServer, "out");
> 
>         //emit response time signal
> emit(responseTimeSignal, simTime() - msgInServer->getTimestamp());
> 
>         //start next packet processing if queue not empty
> if (!queue.isEmpty()) {
> 
>             //No modifications here, technically the queue should be sorted with increasing processing time
> EV << "Queue is not empty" << endl;
> 
>             //Put the next message from the queue inside the server
> msgInServer = (cMessage *)queue.pop();
> 
>             //Emit queue len and queuing time for this packet
> emit(qlenSignal, queue.getLength());
> emit(queueingTimeSignal, simTime() - msgInServer->getTimestamp());
> 
>             //start service
> startPacketService(msg);
> 
>         }
> if (queue.isEmpty()) { //saying it explicitly instead of using "else"
> 
>             //server is not busy anymore
> msgInServer = nullptr;
> serverBusy = false;
> emit(busySignal, serverBusy);
> 
>             //log idle server
> EV << "Empty queue, server goes IDLE" << endl;
>         }
>     }
> else { //packet from source has arrived
> 
>         //Setting arrival timestamp as msg field
> msg->setTimestamp();
> 
> if (serverBusy) {
> 
> EV << "Server was found BUSY, putting new message in the queue..." << endl;
> putPacketInQueue(msg);
> 
>         }
> else { //server idle, start service right away
> 
> EV << "Server was found IDLE, starting service of new message..." << endl;
>             //Put the message in server and start service
> msgInServer = msg;
> startPacketService(msg);
> 
>             //server is now busy
> serverBusy = true;
> emit(busySignal, serverBusy);
> 
>             //queueing time was ZERO
> emit(queueingTimeSignal, SIMTIME_ZERO);
> 
>         }
>     }
> }
> 
> void Queue::startPacketService(cMessage *msq)
> {
> 
>     //generate service time and schedule completion accordingly
> simtime_t serviceTime = exponential(avgServiceTime);
> scheduleAt(simTime()+serviceTime, endOfServiceMsg);
> 
>     //log service start
> EV << "Starting service of " << msgInServer->getName() << " with processing time: " << serviceTime << endl;
> 
> }
> 
> void Queue::putPacketInQueue(cMessage *msg)
> {
> cQueue queue("queue", MyCompareFunc); //seems to work better here
> queue.insert(msg);
> emit(qlenSignal, queue.getLength());
> 
>     //log new message in queue
> simtime_t serviceTime = exponential(avgServiceTime);
> EV << msg->getName() << " enters queue with processing time: " << serviceTime << endl;
> }
> 
>
```

This code does something but I'm not sure what: meaning I see the messages being serviced in a different order than the one they come in, but I can't understand if it's the order I intended. Also it's almost like every time the comparison between two messages is done, the one with longest service time is dropped/discarded.

Can anybody help? Thank you!

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and paste the code without the `>` so that people can copy & paste it to try it? Indentation would also be helpful, while you're editing anyway. I don't know omnet, so take these with a grain of salt: Is that code a [mcve]? How do you run it? What inputs do you use? What is the actual vs the expected output? See also [ask].

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one serious C++ misunderstanding in the presented code - `queue` is a member of class `cQueue`:

```
class Queue : public cSimpleModule {
   protected:
     cMessage *msgInServer;
     cMessage *endOfServiceMsg;
     cQueue queue;
     // ...
```

However, in `putPacketInQueue()` a local variable `queue` is created.

```
void Queue::putPacketInQueue(cMessage *msg) { 
   cQueue queue("queue", MyCompareFunc);
   queue.insert(msg);
   // ...
```

In C++ lifetime of a local (non-static) variable is limited to its scope - here to `putPacketInQueue()`. As a consequence, in `putPacketInQueue()` a message is inserted into an instance of `cQueue` that is destroyed a few lines later.